# Entity framework optional 1 to 1 relation on both ends

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Most questions I have found were not the type I am looking for.

I have 2 tables:

```
public class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public Guid? CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

A `User` can exists without being a `Customer` and a `Customer` can exist without being an `User`.

I tried the fluent API like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasOptional<User>(c => c.User)
    .WithOptionalDependent(c => c.Customer)
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("UserId"));
```

But it keeps giving me this error when I try to create the migration:

`Customer_User_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Customer_User_Source' in relationship 'Customer_User'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.`

**Update**

I changed my model to this:

```
public class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

With the fluent API:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Customer>()
    .HasOptional(l => l.User)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .Map(k => k.MapKey("CustomerId"));

modelBuilder
    .Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.Customer)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .Map(k => k.MapKey("UserId"));
```

This seems to work but is there a way to define the column in the model instead of having to use `MapKey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658619/unable-to-determine-principal-end-entity-framework-code-first-relationship)

And [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021135/ef-code-first-1-to-1-optional-relationship) too

The problem with that links is I'm not sure if they provide a actual solution to the problem: because I don't know if it provide uniqueness for the foreign key in both tables (as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462312/entity-framework-model-first-10-1-relationship) suggest). Because that, not having EF unique constraints, you have to create it manually (in the generator)

And finally [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152041/ef4-self-referencing-with-association-0-1-1?lq=1) explains that the unique form of performing an 1:* relationship is using the foreign key of one of the tables as primary key of the other.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks the 2nd link pointed me in the right direction, do you perhaps have an answer on my edit?

Comment: I read it yeah. I think it's more a culprit in the EF implementation. I created the tables model first and then generated code first from that. EF actually made it an 1..* relation instead of a 1..1 relation.